# serializeArray input data wont pass thought ajax using dynamic adding

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function SendData(){
    var postData = $("#xForm").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: postData,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
    console.log("failure send");
    }
    });
}


    $('#sub-comfirm').on('submit',  function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        SendData();
    });



function PostImgCreate(imgValue){
    var pImg = $("#mydata");

    var inputblock = "";
    inputblock += '<input type="hidden" id="canvasData" name="canvasData">';
    pImg.html(inputblock);

    var elem = document.getElementById("canvasData");
    elem.value = imgValue;
}
```

my intention is to use serializeArray get all my input data thought php , problem is if add my input "canvasData" using function **PostImgCreate** , my php dont get the data at all.

but if i add the input "canvasData" directly to html field , the data pass thought my php.
why? i cant pass my data if i adding input using function ?

Comment: Where do you call `PostImgCreate`?

Comment: in other function ,but postImgcreate already called before they can click submit.

Comment: And are you making sure you are not adding more than one of them? Is mydata  inside of xForm?

Comment: i checked the input is added and yes only one of the input is added , there is noting wrong on the data too. it just dont show at my php result . but if i add the input on html , i get the data on my php.

Comment: i have no idea why isit so werid.

Comment: I have a feeling you are not adding the input where you think you are. If you change `pImg.html(inputblock);` to be `$("#xForm").append(inputblock);` does it work?

Comment: still cannot , i dont think is the create input problem , i think is the adding value , maybe is because i added the value before the input was set ? which somehow create problem ?

Comment: Well your issue is impossible to debug from this end.

Comment: Do you have a form in a form? What is the basic HTML of your set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set it up below and everything you provided is working. You need to look at your HTML code and see if something is different from what I have.

Do you have a form in a form? If yes, that is invalid html and will cause issues.
Do you have `mydata` in the wrong location? Would cause the searlize to not find it.

```js
function SendData() {
  PostImgCreate("XYZ");
  var postData = $("#xForm").serializeArray();
  console.log(postData);
}


$('#sub-comfirm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  SendData();
});


function PostImgCreate(imgValue) {
  var pImg = $("#mydata");

  if(!pImg.find("#canvasData").length) {
      var inputblock = "";
      inputblock += '<input type="hidden" id="canvasData" name="canvasData">';
      pImg.html(inputblock);
  }

  var elem = document.getElementById("canvasData");
  elem.value = imgValue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form id="xForm">
    <input name="xxx" type "text" value="testtest" />
    <span id="mydata"></span>
  </form>


<form id="sub-comfirm">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```